# Web Deployment Projects - Remote IIS Server

Tags: asp.net, iis, deployment, msbuild, web-deployment-project

## Background

In the spirit of continuous integration, I'm trying to automate our deployment process using a Web Deployment Project.  Mostly, this has been painless.  Most options were baked in and those that weren't were easy to add through the MSBuild XML interface.

However, I cannot seem to find an option for deploying to a remote IIS Server.  This seems strange to me because I obviously don't want all my builds to run on my production/staging server.

## The Question

How can I set up my Web Deployment project to create/overwrite an IIS Virtual Directory on a remote machine?

## Notes

I am using `Visual Studio 2008` and `.net 3.0`.

## [Edit]

As suggested by [x0n](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6920/x0n) below, I could use MS Deploy for this.  I would rather use a Web Deployment Project though, especially since we already have those set up.  :)

Comment: Are you deploying Web Site Projects or Web Application Projects?  The deployment steps are typically much easier (xcopy) with WAP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your best bet is to take a look at MS Deploy which is available as a stand-alone package right now at RC level. It ships with a Go-Live license, which means it will be compatible with the version shipping with Visual Studio 2010. Some info:

http://blogs.iis.net/msdeploy/default.aspx

It's a great tool - will sync remote servers, farms etc picking up missing metabase info, com objects, registry, .net components in bin or gac, databases - the whole hog. It also ships with an interactive shell and powershell cmdlets.

-Oisin

Comment: Thanks x0n, I will definitely check it out.  +1